# How to render views from subdirectories in node js?

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js, laravel-blade, express-handlebars

In Blade for rendering a view in the subdirectory 'admin' we do as follows :

```
return view('admin.profile');
```

Directory : views/admin/profile.blade.php

How do I render the same view in node js (Handlebars)

```
router.get('/admin',(req,res)=>{
     res.render('admin/profile');
      });
```

Comment: `res.render('admin/profile.blade')`, I guess you are trying t render a HTML page? else read that file using `fs.js` and use `res.send(fileData)`.

Comment: I want to render profile view in the admin folder

Comment: I got the answer from Ethan Brown's Book, Thank you